# How to make main return char[]

Tags: java, program-entry-point, return-type

I'm making a program to read and write to xml files the problem is that this program, which I'm calling initializer, is going to be called by another program, which I'm calling machine, and the initializer has to return a char array to the machine.
Here is the main function:

```
public static char[] main(String[] args) throws SaxonApiException, IOException, NoSuchMethodException {
        define elementos = new define();
        if (args.length >= 1) {
            file = args[0] + ".xml";
        } else {
            System.out.print("Não foram encontrados argumentos\n");
            exit(200);
        }
        Document doc = inicialização.pos.XMLJDomFunctions.lerDocumentoXML(file);
        if ("adiciona".equals(args[1])) {
            if (args.length >= 3) {
                doc = adicionaTabelaFicheiro(args[2].split(" ")[0], args[2].split(" ")[1], doc, elementos);
                String c = "0";
                return c.toCharArray();
            }
        }
        if ("altera".equals(args[1])) {
            if (args.length >= 3) {
                doc = alteraTabelaFicheiro(args[2].split(" ")[0], args[2].split(" ")[1], doc, elementos);
                String c = "0";
                return c.toCharArray();
            }
        }
        if ("le".equals(args[1])) {
            if (args.length >= 3) {
                char[] c;
                c = leTabela(args[2].split(" ")[0], doc, elementos);
                return c;
            }
        }
        String c = "400";
        return c.toCharArray();
    }
```

As you can see here the main has char[] returning type but when I try to run it says no main classes found

[image]

Comment: The main returns nothing - Where should it return to? Print it to the console.

Comment: You can name your methods as you wish, but java will always look for a `public static void main(String[])` to execute.

Comment: How are you calling your 'initialiser' program? How do you expect it to return information to your 'machine' program?

Comment: A `main()` method has to be defined in a specific way. Rethink your design if you need to pass data between classes. In fact, if another class is going to call this class with the `main()`method, you probably don't want a `main()` method in the class you'll be calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main method in Java must look as follows:

`public static void main(String[] args) {...}`

It doesn't have a return-type. I would suggest you to rename your method, if possible. Still bare in mind that you have to define your main method somewhere in order to execute the program.